# Dedupe records without DELETE

Tags: sql, sql-server, deduplication

I need to bring back only one of the records from a duplicated row in SQL Server

I have data like this

```
-------------------------------------------
CustomerID, OrderID, ProductID, Title
-------------------------------------------
1,1001,131,orange
1,1002,131,orange
-------------------------------------------
```

These rows are shown as 2 items that have been ordered by the same person, really they are just two as the quantity chosen in the basket and 2 records.

My question is how can i retrieve only one of these rows?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

First some test data:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(CustomerID INT,OrderID INT,ProductID INT,Title VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @tbl
VALUES
    (1,1001,131,'orange'),
    (1,1002,131,'orange')
```

Then the query

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY tbl.CustomerID,tbl.ProductID,tbl.Title 
              ORDER BY tbl.OrderID) AS RowNbr,
        tbl.CustomerID,
        tbl.OrderID,
        tbl.ProductID,
        tbl.Title
    FROM
        @tbl AS tbl
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    CTE
WHERE
    CTE.RowNbr=1
```

Comment: I don't think this achieves the desired results. Since you're partitioning by every single column, `iRank` will *ALWAYS* be `1`. Fix your sample data (change second `OrderID` to `1002`, for example, to match what the OP had in the question) and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: This is a very good strategy when the criteria for the first record gets complicated and involves many fields and calculation.

Comment: @Jeff O : Yeah thats also true thats why I used a CTE in this case. Because I did not know that the OP wanted with the result

Comment: I prefer the CTE solution as well, it's not always just *one* column we're trying to de-dupe. The `MIN`/`MAX` tricks break down quickly.

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand: yeah totally agree. I also think that it is preferably because it is easy to read and change are not hard to implement because there is no group by.

Comment: @Sandeep Bansal: Glad to help

Answer (score 4):

This way you can get, not only one of both rows, but also the quantity ordered

```
SELECT 
   CustomerID, ProductID, Title, max(OrderID) as orderID, COUNT(*) as quantity
FROM 
  TableName 
GROUP BY 
   CustomerID, 
   ProductID, 
   Title
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Max will get you the most recent order

```
SELECT CustomerID, MAX(OrderId), ProductID, Title
FROM table
GROUP BY CustomerID, ProductID, Title
```

OR

Using Min will get you the first order

```
SELECT CustomerID, MIN(OrderId), ProductID, Title
FROM table
GROUP BY CustomerID, ProductID, Title
```

Comment: That won't do. The orderIDs are different.

Answer (score 1):

Provided that it's really what you want you can get the first order of each order with the same customer, product and title using a grouping and the MIN function (MAX would give you the last order):

```
SELECT CustomerID, MIN(OrderID) AS OrderID, ProductID, Title 
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY CustomerID, ProductID, Title
```

If you want the number of duplicate orders (that would be the ordered quantity judging by your question) you can add a count:

```
SELECT CustomerID, MIN(OrderID) AS OrderID, ProductID, Title, 
    COUNT(*) AS Quantity 
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY CustomerID, ProductID, Title
```